# Environment variable is always null. Kotlin Spring

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, environment-variables

I am having trouble with environment variables in spring.
I want to retrieve the name of the serviceAccount file, I will need this for my firestore db, depending on if my application is running on my prod, test or dev environment.

Here is the application.yml file im working with - the environment variables are set in AWS.

```
spring:
 profiles: aws
contentapi:
 apikey: ${APIKEY}
firestore:
 serviceAccount: ${SDKPATH:serviceAccount_dev.json}
```

Here my default/fallback value is the dev serviceAccount

I did read here on Stackoverflow that the @value variables isn't initialised before after the constructor is done.

The problem is that I have to use the variable for my connection to my database..

I have tried the @value annotation, System.env and all the other suggestions I could find here, but none worked.

How do I solve this? It seems that the variable is always null..

Here is my code

```
@Configuration
@Service
class ArticleService {

@Value("\${contentapi.apikey}")
lateinit var contentapiKey:String

@Value("\${firestore.serviceAccount}")
lateinit var serviceAccount:String

var articleIds = ArrayList<String>()
var articleIdsNotSaved = ArrayList<String>()

private val articleContentApi = "https://content.watchmedier.dk/api/jyllands-posten/content/article/"

private val firebaseAdminSDK = this.javaClass.classLoader.getResourceAsStream(serviceAccount)

private val options = FirebaseOptions.Builder()
        .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(firebaseAdminSDK))
        .setDatabaseUrl("https://myprojectid.firebaseio.com")
        .build()!!
private val firestore = FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options)
val databaseReference = FirestoreClient.getFirestore(firestore)


fun fetchRecommendations( appId:String, siteName:String, max:String, context:String) {
```

Answer (score 0):

The application.yml seems to be the problem.

If it is updated to this:

```
contentapi:
  baseurl: https://content.watchmedier.dk
  apikey: Test
firestore:
  serviceAccount: testing
server:
  port: 8080

---
spring:
  profiles: aws
contentapi:
  apikey: ${APIKEY:Test}
firestore:
  serviceAccount: ${SDKPATH:erviceAccount_dev.json}
```

The property will be set to "testing"
So for some reason the profile isn't getting set. I have of course set the profile in my configuration (local run)

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use annotations you should at least avoid using injection by attributes. And use injection by constructor (avoid using lateinit). This will be more suitable for your problem because you need the properties for constructing your service. I'll change your code for something like:

```
@Service
class ArticleService(@Value("\${contentapi.apikey}") private val contentApiKey: String, @Value("\${firestore.serviceAccount}") private val serviceAccount: String) {

    private val articleContentApi = "https://content.watchmedier.dk/api/jyllands-posten/content/article/"
    private var firebaseAdminSDK: InputStream

    init {
        firebaseAdminSDK = this.javaClass.classLoader.getResourceAsStream(serviceAccount)
    }
}
```

But if you are using spring-boot and kotlin you should take advantage of kotlin dsl:

```
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder
import org.springframework.context.support.beans
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment
import java.io.InputStream

class ArticleService(private val contentApiKey: String, private val serviceAccount: String) {

    private val articleContentApi = "https://content.watchmedier.dk/api/jyllands-posten/content/article/"
    private var firebaseAdminSDK: InputStream

    init {
        firebaseAdminSDK = this.javaClass.classLoader.getResourceAsStream(serviceAccount)
    }
}

@SpringBootApplication
class ServiceApp

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    SpringApplicationBuilder()
            .sources(ServiceApp::class.java)
            .initializers(beans {
        bean {
            val properties = ref<Environment>()

            ArticleService(properties.getProperty("contentapi.apikey")!!, properties.getProperty("firestore.serviceAccount")!!)
        }
    }).run(*args)
}
```

Comment: This code gives me a "unresolved reference" when using contentApiKey in my functions, and the line, private var firebaseAdminSDK: InputStream return a "property must be initialized or abstract"

Comment: when using code example #2 how would i get the property from the bean?

Comment: I still get the same error "could not resolve placeholder 'firestore.serviceAccount in value "${firestore.serviceAccount}""

Comment: In the first example i forgot the others variable. Add them and initialize them in the init block. If you get couldn't resolve it means that it can't be found in any property source.

Comment: It seems that my application.yml is the problem.

Comment: Is it a valid yaml ? Where is it located ?